# Export Android Package for Google Play

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a very strange problem:

After updating Eclipse the "Export Signed Application Package" Function throws an error (Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".)

Now it is impossible for me to publish my Android APP in Google Play.

How can I sign my application (.apk) without using eclipse? The "normal" .apk Package has been built successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Signing Your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) for how to sign an application outside of Eclipse.

On a side note, I would suggested uninstalling then reinstalling Eclipse and the SDK.